# How would I use a attribute or a element that will split my data from adding with each other

Tags: python

```
import quadratic
ranges = int(input("what is the range"))
for a in range (0,ranges):
    x= int (input ("what is x"))
    y= quadratic.get_y_value (x)
    print (y)
```

I am importing a quadratic equation, how would I be able to store the y values, without adding this y value together. Also I'm not that confident with for loops and my teacher wants me to use for loops. After storing the y values, I want to display these values in a table of values.

```
 import quadratic
temp=int
mylist= []
maxranges = int(input("how high do you want to go"))
minranges = int (input("how low do you want to go"))
#note that you set the minimum threshold and that if you do enter a value under that low threshold it will be a incorrect response
if minranges>maxranges:
    temp=maxranges
    maxranges=minranges
    minranges = temp
    print (maxranges)
    print (minranges)
for a in range (minranges,maxranges):
    x= int (input ("what is x"))
    y= quadratic.get_y_value (x)
    print (y)
    mylist.append((x,y))
print ("it is now in a chart, have a look:",mylist)
```

*revised copy with the help of the mvps

Comment: add values of `y` in `list`, so we can use list of `y` values for print or other process

Comment: It seems like your asking for programming therapy. What is your problem?

Comment: And by the way, I don't see why is it you'd need to store another set of y values as they already seem to be stored in the quadratic module.

Comment: @VivekSable how would i implement this list element into my code?

Comment: well the quadratic equation is just a general equation, i just need the user to enter x values so that it can be calculated and printed back out in a table of values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just **define list variable outside of for loop** and use list `append()` method to add values in list.

e.g.

```
>>> list_y = []
>>> for i in range(0,5):
...    print i
...    list_y.append(i)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
>>> print list_y
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

---

If we want to save two values x and y then add tuple in the list.

e.g.

```
>>> result = []
>>> for i in range(0,5):
...    result.append((i, i+1))
... 
>>> print result
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
>>>
```

Comment: what if i wanted to put the x values right next to it?

Comment: like x (0,1,2,3), y (0,1,2,3)

Comment: @adenli Welcome :) just up vote or accept my answer to get me some points. :D

Comment: I think list comprehensions are better for simple operations like this. Especially, for function evaluation and ranges.

Comment: yes, list comprehensions is good way. but his just started programming so for beginner best way to go step by step to understand coding.

Comment: @adenli Are you really going to pray to a man for the rest of your life for the simplest programming problem? You sound like you just earned a job with this code.

Comment: lmao i pray to gabe too

Comment: one more question, how would i be able to pluck out a maximum value from this equation and a minimum value like as a set. ex: maximum (2,10), minimum (-1,4)

Comment: @adenli: how we can identify (2,10) is max and (-1,4) is min ??

Comment: can you implement that in a chunk of code so i can further understand?

Comment: `mylist` have `(x.y)` values, use max and min method to get item from list. Out we want to do with `mylist`?? Can you shear problem definition with us or me(vivekbsable@gmail.com) ? So I can think  according to input and output?

Comment: i got it now, no worries

Comment: @adenli: Good, and Welcome.  If you have any query related to python programming you can ask me. I can be reached anytime via email at vivekbsable@gmail.com, for my skype id: vivek.igp.

Answer (score 0):

You can store values in a list.

First create a list

```
mylist = []
```

Adding two values to the list

```
y = 3
mylist.append(y)
y = 6
mylist.append(y)
```

Printing the list

```
print mylist
[3,6]
```

Comment: Thanks, wanna hire me? ;)

Comment: Hire you? What, for this?

Comment: well i can confirm your prolly older than me

Comment: im 15 lmao, late baby problems

Comment: @MalikBrahimi It's Sunday, chill!

Comment: well it is monday in hong kong

Answer (score 0):

First of all, range is usually a two part interval, so I don't know why you only input one number:

```
a, b = [int(i) for i in input().split()][:2] # the interval [a, b]
```

Secondly, you need to create a list y values to a new list, so that you can use the values later:

```
y_values = [quadratic.get_y_value(i) for i in range(a, b + 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
list2 = []
for i in range(0, ranges):
    list1 = []
    list1.append(y)
    list1.append(x)
    list2.append(list1)
print("X|Y")
for i, j in list2:
    print(i, j)
```

There are probably better ways of doing this but this works.